# Is it possible to change the Lightning-input label to bold without the value field

Tags: lightning-web-components

In my LWC html template I use  which is works perfectly. But recently I came across a requirement that says to bold just the label and not the input value field. Below is an example of the code (ignore the":" i know they do not belong.

```
<:lightning-input
   type="date"
   label="First Payment Date"
   value={xyz}
   onchange={xyzchnage}
></lightning-input:>
```

I am unable to put the  attribute surrounding the label but I am wrap completely around it. Example:

```
<:b><:lightning-input
    type="date"
    label="Bold Focus Text"
    value={xyz}
    onchange={xyzchnage}
></lightning-input><:/b>
```

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> <legend class="slds-form-element__legend slds-form-element__label">Desired Label</legend>
> <lightning-input
>   variant="label-hidden"
> ></lightning-input>
> ```

This give the Label a heavy weight (makes it look bold compared to other labels in the lightning page

Answer (score 2):

### Easy-ish way

Use the [variant attribute](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification) to hide the label and create your own label for the component.

### The hardest way

[Visit the slds website to get the HTML behind the component](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/input/#site-main-content).

Then you can do what ever you want. This approach would require quite a lot of extra work to get it to behave exactly correctly so I would weigh the work to the value. This seems like a high-effort, low-value requirement.

Comment: +1. In the easy-ish method, how will you do label-stacked/inline based on user preference?

Comment: When doing the easier approach, the labels do not align with other labels. So from a GUI perspective it does not look good.

Comment: @Sharif91 It's your job to make it look good.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way. Use css class

```
.strong-text {
     font-weight: bold;
}

<lightning-input
   class="strong-text"
   type="date"
   label="Bold Focus Text"
   value={xyz}
   onchange={xyzchnage}
>
</lightning-input>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. thanks, ton.

Comment: This will result in the values being in bold too.